# Create Pricing Table using HTML, CSS

Tags: html-table

I tried to create a [responsive pricing table](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business#compareProductsRegion), but not working.

I tried below way but it's not working. I tried to google but I can't figure out the useful links.

Please suggest me to do this right away.

```css
     .table tr.hide-table-padding td {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .expand-button {
        position: relative;
    }
    .accordion-toggle .expand-button:after {
        position: absolute;
        left:.75rem;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
        content: '-';
    }
    .accordion-toggle.collapsed .expand-button:after {
        content: '+';
    }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">/* Chart.js */
    @-webkit-keyframes chartjs-render-animation{from{opacity:0.99}to{opacity:1}}@keyframes chartjs-render-animation{from{opacity:0.99}to{opacity:1}}.chartjs-render-monitor{-webkit-animation:chartjs-render-animation 0.001s;animation:chartjs-render-animation 0.001s;}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th> 
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="accordion-toggle collapsed" id="accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
            <td class="expand-button"></td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        
        
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Please suggest me to create the same as.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width: 100%` to fill the screen horizontally:

```css
.table tr.hide-table-padding td {
  padding: 0;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.expand-button {
  position: relative;
}

.accordion-toggle .expand-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: .75rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  content: '-';
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed .expand-button:after {
  content: '+';
}

</style><style type="text/css">
/* Chart.js */

@-webkit-keyframes chartjs-render-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0.99
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes chartjs-render-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 0.99
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.chartjs-render-monitor {
  -webkit-animation: chartjs-render-animation 0.001s;
  animation: chartjs-render-animation 0.001s;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        <th scope="col">Heading</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="accordion-toggle collapsed" id="accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
        <td class="expand-button"></td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
        <td>Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```